# Can you ever get trapped in samsara again after Moksha because of Karma?

Tags: moksha

If one attains Moksha -That is what frees a person from samsara. So it wont matter if you lie,steal or doing anything like that since you have already freed yourself so you wont get reborn hence the law of karma will be absolved from you since it only applies to our physical body/the material world. If one is self realized (has attained moksha/enlightenmet/samadhi/jnana or whatever you want to call it), then you wont get reborn, so Karma wont effect you after this body dies, rather it will ONLY affect you NOW in this life because you wont be reborn so it cant wait until next life but rather has to act upon you during this life since this is the last time you will be trapped in this world, yes or no?
Simply put what I am asking is related to antinomianism. That is its by grace(knowledge) we are saved and not by deeds, yes or no?
so if grace(knowledge) has already saved us, we cant erase that and become unsaved again through our actions even if the action is "bad" or what christians would call it a "sin", because we are already "saved" by knowledge, thats why Karma cant make you get reborn.

Comment: "so Karma wont effect you after this body dies, rather it will ONLY affect you NOW in this life" Karma does not work this way. It is applicable across time until it is balanced out. Second, someone who has attained moksha does not deliberately court actions that add karma to their jeeva. Third, moksha is attained by a combination of our effort (actions) and grace. The premises of this question are incorrect.

Comment: This question needs to be better researched and then reworked. We are not "saved by grace" through faith or knowledge.